# How to make my div stay in the viewport vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the brick breaker game in vanilla js (without canvas) and I managed to make the racket move by changing the "left" style on key down event, but because of "left" style, the racket is only 50% visible if I get at the right or left end of the screen (like in the screen below).

And what I want to do is just to say like "if you touch the left or right side of the screen, you can't go further" but I also think it's because of the "left: 0%" thing

[when the racket is in the middle of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdUP9.png)

[when it's on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaSud.png)

And here is my code :

```
    <body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <div id="racket"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var racket = document.getElementById("racket");
      var left = 50;

      racket.style.left = left + "%";

      document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
        let arrow = event.key;

        while (arrow === "ArrowLeft" && left > 0) {
          left += -1;
          racket.style.left = left + "%";

          break;
        }
        while (arrow === "ArrowRight" && left < 100) {
          left += +1;
          racket.style.left = left + "%";
          break;
        }

        if (left <= 0) {
          racket.style.left = "0%";
        } else if (left >= 100) {
          racket.style.left = "100%";
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

That's the html and js (there is nothing more), and for the css :

```
    *,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#racket {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  width: 70px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
```

If you can help me, thank you very much

Comment: You have to take into account the width of the racket.

Comment: And the width of the container.

Comment: In order to help, it would be nice if you gave us enough code to reproduce the problem. This means that your CSS is required, and possibly more of your HTML and JS.